# Reading nested custom objects from SQLite with sqflite in flutter

Tags: sql, database, flutter, sqlite, sqflite

I am developing an application in **Flutter** and use **sqflite** library to store app data locally. And Firebase is my online database choice. The application revolves around gym and workouts. I have **3 classes** to store the data for a workout which are structured like this:

```
class Workout {
  String workoutID, title;
  List<Exercise> exercises;
  User owner;

  Workout({
    required this.workoutID,
    required this.title,
    required this.exercises,
    required this.owner,
    });
}
```

```
class Exercise {
  String exerciseID;
  List<WorkoutSet> sets;

  Exercise({
    required this.exerciseID,
    required this.sets,
    });
}
```

```
class WorkoutSet {
  String setID;
  int? reps, rest;

  WorkoutSet({
    required this.setID,
    this.reps = 0,
    this.rest = 0,
  });
}
```

There are **three tables** in the database to store these data. **workouts - exercises - sets**.
There is no problem with storing these data into sqlite, but I was unable to come up with a **logic to read the workouts** from the database. Does anybody know any standard and professional way to read the workouts and show them in the home screen? Thanks in advance.